# On a definition of subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I know that a subset $H$ of a group $G$ is a subgroup if

(a)If $a$ and $b$ are in $H$, so is $ab$.

(b)1(the identity) is in $H$

(c)If $a$ is in $H$, so is $a^{-1}$.

I am wondering if the condition $(b)$ is unnecessary. The definition seemed to assume that the $a^{-1}$ in $H$ is the same as the $a^{-1}$ in $G$.Thus, $1$ serves as the identity in both $H$ and $G$. Is there any gap in my understanding?

Comment: Without condition (b) the empty set would be a subgroup.

Comment: There is at least three (equivalent) definitions of a subgroup. Thus I have changed your title here.

Comment: If you replace (b) by "$H$ is nonempty", the resultant criterion is equivalent to yours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The argument
$$ 
a \in H \underset{(c)}{\implies} a^{-1} \in H \underset{(a)}{\implies} 1 = a a^{-1} \in H
$$
works only if there *is* an $a \in H$. The empty set [vacuously](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth) satisfies conditions (a) and (c), but not (b). By definition, the empty set is not a group.

If you exclude that case then your argument is correct: A *nonempty* subset $H$ of a group $G$ is a subgroup exactly if (a) and (c) are satisfied.

Comment: And if $H$ is finite, then (a) suffices.